# Error while installing Python TA-lib package on Linux system with no sudo privileges

Tags: python, linux, finance, algorithmic-trading, ta-lib

I'm having trouble installing the python `talib` package on a linux system (`Linux 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64`). See https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib
.

What I did so far:

- `brew install ta-lib` (Dependency)

  - This worked fine. If I rerun this command I see `Warning: ta-lib-0.4.0 already installed`
- `pip install ta-lib`

  - when running this, I get the following error: `error: command /home/username/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1`

**I don't have `sudo` privileges on this machine**, so I suspect this might be a problem. I also tried

```
pip install --user ta-lib
```

and

```
wget https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/archive/master.zip && unzip master.zip && cd ta-lib-master && python setup.py install.
```

Same error as above.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also get stuck at this problem. Then I found two ways to solve this. This problem is because ta-lib installation only check several dirs, which not include linuxbrew path. You have two ways to solve this problem.

1. Follow the instructions on https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib, download "[ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz)", and manually install ta-lib
2. run the following code in shell, (you may need to change the path to ta-lib or ta-lib version)

   export TA_INCLUDE_PATH='/home/username/.linuxbrew/Cellar/ta-lib/0.4.0/include'

   export TA_LIBRARY_PATH='/home/username/.linuxbrew/Cellar/ta-lib/0.4.0/lib'

then run "pip install ta-lib"